# PHP CURL returns headers inside of body

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am trying to make a proxy for my project, so I took [this proxy](https://github.com/jonycheung/php-stateful-proxy) , and for some reason when I access my site, it displays this: [image]

This is my code:

```php
<?php

error_reporting(0);

// DESCRIPTION: 
//      A session aware php proxy. 
// AUTHOR: Jonathan Cheung
// 
// Prerequisite:
//      - A writable directory
//      - CURL and PHP-CURL
//      - PHP session enabled
// 
// Usage:
//  Use GET, POST, DELETE, PUT method to pass in the 2 parameters:
//      - url : (String) - URI encoded URL of the server address.
//              * Note: When using GET, please URI encode the parameters before appending to the url
//                      E.G.    If this is the actual call "http://www.example.com/api/?name=xxx&email=yyy.com",
//                              your string should be "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fapi%2F%3Fname%3Dxxx%26email%3Dyyy.com"
//                              so that your proxy URL would be proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fapi%2F%3Fname%3Dxxx%26email%3Dyyy.com
//      - clearCookie : (String) true | false - tells the proxy to start a new local session.
//  
// 
// 

//  CONFIGURATION:
//
// filePrefix is the prefix of the local folder for the cookie files
// fileSuffix is the suffix of the local folder for the cookie files
//  e.g. 
//      IF
//          $filePrefix = "/tmp/CURLCOOKIE_";
//          $fileSuffix = "_file.cookie";
//          XXXXXX is your session ID
//      THEN your files will be stored in:
//          "/tmp/CURLCOOKIE_XXXXXX_file.cookie"
// 
$filePrefix = "/tmp/CURLCOOKIE_";
$fileSuffix = "";

session_start();
$url = "http://c3b2-2-34-25-151.ngrok.io/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//Start the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);


if (!$_SESSION['cookiefile'] || $_REQUEST['clearCookie'] == 'true')
{   
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id ();
    $_SESSION['cookiefile'] = $filePrefix.session_id().$fileSuffix;
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);

    // uncomment to log
    // error_log(session_id()."\n\n", 3, "/var/tmp/my-sessions.log");
    
}else{

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SESSION['cookiefile']);
}   
//echo "cookie" .$_SESSION['cookiefile'];

// If it's a POST, put the POST data in the body
if ($_POST ) {
 $requestvars = "";
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){
    if ($requestvars !== "") $requestvars .= "&";
    $requestvars .=$key."=".$val;
 }
    // uncomment to log
    // error_log($postvars."\n\n", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
}

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){

    case "GET":
    break;
    case "POST":
        curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestvars);
    break;
    case "DELETE":
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE"); 
    break;
    case "PUT":
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); 
    break;
}


//Save CURL COOKIES upon curl_close()
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SESSION['cookiefile']);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);

// Make the call
$response = curl_exec($session) or die("CURL Error");

list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n",(string)$response,2);

$count =0;
foreach (explode("\r\n", $headers) as $hdr){
    if($count <1)   {
/*      echo $hdr; */
        header($hdr); 
    }
    $count++;
} 

echo $body;

// uncomment to log
// error_log($response."\n\n", 3, "/var/tmp/my-response.log");

curl_close($session); 

?>
```

How do I remove that text from the body without removing any of the functionality? ( I still need it to do redirects and save cookies, no functionality has to be lost )

, Thanks for helping!

Comment: Looks like splitting the response at a double line break went wrong. Have you checked what `$response` actually contains?